# Python: How to print my simple poem

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I would like to know how I could print out sentences using my triplet poem program.
My program randomly picks a list of nouns to use.

My program:

```
import random

def nouns():
    nounPersons = ["cow","crowd","hound","clown"];
    nounPlace = ["town","pound","battleground","playground"];
    rhymes = ["crowned","round","gowned","found","drowned"];

    nounPersons2 = ["dog","frog","hog"];
    nounPlace2 = ["fog","Prague","smog"];
    rhymes2 = ["log","eggnog","hotdog"];

    nounList1 = [nounPersons,nounPlace,rhymes]
    nounList2 = [nounPersons2,nounPlace2,rhymes2]
    nounsList = [nounList1, nounList2]
    randomPick = random.choice(nounsList)
    return(randomPick)

verbs = ["walked","ran","rolled","biked","crawled"];
nouns()
```

For example, I could have "The cow walked to the town. But then it was drowned." And just replace the nouns/rhyme(cow, town,drowned) and verb(walked) with my randomizer.

Would I use random.randint in some way?

I just basically need a general print statement like the example I showed using my randomizer to randomly pick between the nouns/rhymes.

Comment: you might wanna learn about python string formating https://pyformat.info/

Comment: `nounsList = [nounList1, nounList2]` this isn't how you concatenate lists.

Comment: Also, don't end statements with semicolons, a linebreak does the job just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual (for me), there may be a more Pythonic approach, but to get what you have working, I did three things:

1. assigned your call to the nouns() function to 'chosen_list' variable. That way the returned 'randomPick' gets used.
2. built in a selection step to get individual words from the lists in 'chosen_list' and your verb list
3. added a final print statement with formatting to assemble the words in to a sentence

the code:

```
import random
def nouns():

    nounPersons = ["cow","crowd","hound","clown"];
    nounPlace = ["town","pound","battleground","playground"];
    rhymes = ["crowned","round","gowned","found","drowned"];

    nounPersons2 = ["dog","frog","hog"];
    nounPlace2 = ["fog","Prague","smog"];
    rhymes2 = ["log","eggnog","hotdog"];

    nounList1 = [nounPersons,nounPlace,rhymes]
    nounList2 = [nounPersons2,nounPlace2,rhymes2]
    nounsList = [nounList1, nounList2]
    randomPick = random.choice(nounsList)

    return randomPick

verbs = ["walked","ran","rolled","biked","crawled"]

# this is change 1.
chosen_list = nouns()

# select single words from lists - this is change 2.

noun_subj = random.choice(chosen_list[0])
noun_obj = random.choice(chosen_list[1])
rhyme_word = random.choice(chosen_list[2])
verb_word = random.choice(verbs)

# insert words in to text line - this is change 3.

print ("The {} {} to the {}. But then it was {}.".format(noun_subj, verb_word, noun_obj, rhyme_word))
```